# Android, cannot implement SlidingPaneLayout, fails at setContentView

Tags: android, slidingpanelayout

I asked this already but nobody answered so I'm asking again. I'm trying to implement SlidingPaneLayout from android.support.v4.widget. I'm trying to implement the most barebones code I possibly can. The only way anything will load is if I comment out `setContentView()`. The code *could not* be simpler, and it won't even run without an error. Any help would be hugely appreciated.

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    SlidingPaneLayout paneLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.root_layout);

        /*
        paneLayout = (SlidingPaneLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);
        paneLayout.setPanelSlideListener(new SlidingPaneLayout.SimplePanelSlideListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPanelSlide(View panel, float slideOffset) {
                super.onPanelSlide(panel, slideOffset);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelOpened(View panel) {
                super.onPanelOpened(panel);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPanelClosed(View panel) {
                super.onPanelClosed(panel);
            }
        });
        */
    }
}
```

Main XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--fragment structure follows-->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/content_pane_fragment"
        android:name="com.sonfluence.app.ContentPane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/menu_pane_fragment"
        android:name="com.sonfluence.app.MenuPane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </fragment>

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

The content fragment:

```
package com.sonfluence.app;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

/**
 * Created by c on 5/20/14.
 */
public class ContentPane extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_pane, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

The content XML (I've also tried casting that as a fragment in the xml, nothing):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/content_pane">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
05-20 17:30:29.312  20648-20648/com.sonfluence.app E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.sonfluence.app, PID: 20648
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sonfluence.app/com.sonfluence.app.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
            at com.sonfluence.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: Trying to instantiate a class com.sonfluence.app.ContentPane that is not a Fragment
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
            at com.sonfluence.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java)
            at android.app.Fragment.instantiate(Fragment.java)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreateView(Activity.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java)
            at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java)
            at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java)
            at com.sonfluence.app.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:15)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Hi... try refer to this full tutor http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/10/android-slidingpanelayout-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`s, you need to extend [FragmentActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html) - it is giving you a `ClassCastException` as it is expected an `android.app.Fragment` (as `Activity` does not know about the support versions of Fragments).